# Creating a pandas column of values with a calculation, but change the calculation every x times to a different one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I'm currently creating a new column in my pandas dataframe, which calculates a value based on a simple calculation using a value in another column, and a simple value subtracting from it. This is my current code, which almost gives me the output I desire (example shortened for reproduction):

```
subtraction_value = 3
data = pd.DataFrame({"test":[12, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 10, 9]} 

data['new_column'] = data['test'][::-1] - subtraction_value
```

When run, this gives me the current output:

```
print(data['new_column'])

[9,1,2,1,-2,0,-1,3,7,6]
```

However, if I wanted to use a different value to subtract on the column, from position `[0]`, then use the original subtraction value on positions `[1:3]` of the column, before using the second value on position `[4]` again, and repeat this pattern, how would I do this iteratively? I realize I could use a for loop to achieve this, but for performance reasons I'd like to do this another way. My new output would ideally look like this:

```
subtraction_value_2 = 6

print(data['new_column'])

[6,1,2,1,-5,0,-1,3,4,6]
```

Comment: Except `data` isn't actually a dataframe here - it's a dictionary. Even if it was a DF - it wouldn't give you that output anyway... please make sure to include the exact code you're using.

Comment: what is the point of inverting the Series? This doesn't change a thing because of index alignment

Comment: I've edited to make it a dataframe, and I thought inverting was faster to iterate through? I'm willing to be corrected here, however.

Comment: why would it be faster? Regarding the logic, can you explain differently? "*change the subtraction value every 3 times starting from the first instance*" is quite unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use positional indexing:

```
subtraction_value_2 = 6
col = data.columns.get_loc('new_column')
data.iloc[0::4, col] = data['test'].iloc[0::4].sub(subtraction_value_2)
```

or with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
data['new_column'] = np.where(data.index%4,
                              data['test']-subtraction_value,
                              data['test']-subtraction_value_2)
```

output:

```
   test  new_column
0    12           6
1     4           1
2     5           2
3     4           1
4     1          -5
5     3           0
6     2          -1
7     5           2
8    10           4
9     9           6
```

Comment: Why not `data['new_column'][::4] = data['test'][::4] - subtraction_value_2` to avoid computing `col` first?

Comment: @Tobias for which one? Also really avoid `data['new_column'][::4]` for setting values as this can create a copy and raise a SettingWithCopyWarning (and produce incorrect data)

Comment: @mozway Instead of using row 2 & 3 in positional indexing. But you're right with the warning, you can use `.loc` then instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
subtraction_value = 3
subtraction_value_2 = 6

data = pd.DataFrame({"test":[12, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 10, 9]})

data['new_column'] = data.test - subtraction_value
data['new_column'][::4] = data.test[::4] - subtraction_value_2

print(list(data.new_column))
```

Output:

```
[6, 1, 2, 1, -5, 0, -1, 2, 4, 6]
```